# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<PollField>' of 'function result' stuck

Tags: list, flutter, class, dart

I'm trying to create twitter like poll but I'm facing this problem

****Ignore***
I don't have much to write but it doesn't let me post the question so sorry for this

```
 class Poll extends StatelessWidget {
       final PollController s = Get.put(PollController());
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
            ListView.builder(
          itemCount: s.listController.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            printInfo(info: s.listController[index].hintText);
            return PollItem(
              poll: s.listController[index],
            );
          })
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

--> this is PollItem

```
class PollItem extends StatelessWidget {
 final PollField poll;

  const PollItem({Key key, this.poll}) : super(key: key);
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListTile(
  leading: SizedBox(
    width: 300,
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: poll.hintText),
      controller: poll.controller,
      style: theme(context)
          .textTheme
          .body1
          .copyWith(color: theme(context).accentColor),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

And this is the PollController & I'm using Getx package

```
class PollController extends GetxController {
 static TextEditingController choice1 = TextEditingController();
 static TextEditingController choice2 = TextEditingController();
 static TextEditingController choice3 = TextEditingController();
 static TextEditingController choice4 = TextEditingController();
 List<PollField> listController = [
  PollField(controller: choice1, hintText: 'Choice1'),
  PollField(controller: choice2, hintText: 'Choice2'),
 ];
}
```

this the class for Pollfield

```
 class PollField {
    TextEditingController controller;
    String hintText;
    PollField({this.controller, this.hintText});
   }
```

and this is the Error I'm getting

```
type  'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<PollField>' of 'function result'
```

Comment: So which line is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Your help
When I just restarted the project it starts to work